# Calculating first and follow set of grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar

below is the grammar that i am using for a calculator language and my attempt at finding the follow set and the first set of the grammar.

I would love help in figuring out what i am doing wrong when trying to figure out these sets because I feel like i am not doing them correctly at all (at least for the follow sets)

Grammar

> program → stmt_list $$$
>   stmt_list → stmt stmt_list | ε
>   stmt → id = expr | input id | print expr
>   expr → term term_tail
>   term_tail → add op term term_tail | ε
>   term → factor fact_tail
>   fact_tail → mult_op fact fact_tail | ε
>   factor → ( expr ) | number | id
>   add_op → + | -
>   mult_op → * | / | // | %

First set

> first(p) = {id, input, print}
>   first(stmt_list) = {id, input, print, e}
>   first(s) = {id, input, print}
>   first(expr) = {(, id, number}
>   first(term_tail) = {+, -, e}
>    first(term) = {(, id, number}
>   first(fact_tail) = {*, /, //, %, e}
>
>    first(factor) = {(, id, number}
>
>   first(add_op) = {+, -}
>
>    first(mult_op) = {*, /, //, %}

Follow Set

> follow(p) = {$}
>   follow(stmt_list) = {$}
>   follow(stmt) = {id, input, print}
>   follow(expr) = {(, id, number, ), input, print, *, /, //, %}
>
>   follow(term_tail) = {), (, id, number, print, input}
>
>   follow(term) = {+, -}
>
>   follow(factor) = {*, /, //, %}
>   follow(add_op) = {}
>   follow(mult_op) = {}
>   follow(fact_tail) = {*, /, //, %, +, -}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have certain mistakes in First as well

> first(p) = {id, input, print,e}

it will include epsilon
* is missing in the next two -

```
first(fact_tail) = { *,/, //, %, e} first(mult_op) = {*, /, //, %}
```

> fact_tail → mult_op fact fact_tail | ε

Iam assuming here you actually mean

> fact_tail → mult_op factor fact_tail | ε

**Follow**

> follow(stmt) = {id, input, print,$}

if you refer to

> stmt_list → stmt stmt_list | ε

then stmt is followed by first of stmt_list which includes e so string generated will end, hence stmt is followed by $

> follow(expr) = {(, id, number, ), input, print, , /, //, %}

I don't know how you got this, follow of expr is equal to follow of stmt and )

> follow(expr) = {id, ), input, print,$}
>
> follow(term_tail) is equal to follow(expr)
>
> follow(term) = {+,-,),id,input,print,$}
>
> follow(fact_tail) is equal to follow(term)
>
> follow(factor) = first(fact_tail)
>
> follow(add_op) = first(term)
>
> follow(mult_op) = first(factor)

Comment: so my follow(P) and follow(stmt_list) are both correct?

Comment: Awesome, this really helped me out a lot in figuring out this program.

I can now finally write the program to finish parsing this calculator language!!!